# Don't want the calendar begining by sunday

Tags: actionscript-3, date, calendar

I've got a code that shows a calendar when I click on the icon. Unfortunately, the calendar is begining by Sunday. I would like to begin the week by Monday.

Any idea how I can do that by modifing my code ?

```
import box;

var nM:int = 0;
var row:Number = 0;
var holder_txt:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var myDate = new Date( thisDate.getFullYear(), thisDate.getMonth() + nM );
var startDay = myDate.getDay();

for ( var t:int = 0; t < getDays(myDate); t++ ) 
{
    myArray[t] = (t+1);

    var textNum:String = myArray[t];
    var square:MovieClip = new box();

    square.name = textNum;
    square.texter.text = textNum;
    square.x = (startDay) * 75;
    square.y = (row+1) * 65;

    holder_txt.addChild(square);

    startDay++; 
    if( startDay >= 7 ) { startDay = 0; row++; }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you code is awful ! Could you please put just the part of your code which is concerned by your question or may just a little example ? ...

Comment: Thing is nowhere do you show how the days of the week are tied to the dates. Is `var startDay = myDate.getDay();` supposed to give a number between 1 and 7?? I would expect `myDate.getDay();` to give a number like 27 (for Jan 27th).. Anyway does adding `startDay += 1;` before the FOR loop help the calender start at monday's date instead of sunday's?

Comment: Excellent ! It worked with `startDay -= 1;` ! Thanks !